# Question on tensor core GEMM implementation?

Tags: cuda

I am reading some tensor core [material](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/programming-tensor-cores-cuda-9/) and related code on simple GEMM. I have two question:

1, when using tensor core for `D=A*B+C`, it multiplies two fp16 matrices 4x4 and adds the multiplication product fp32 matrix to fp32 accumulator.Why two fp16 input multiplication `A*B`results in fp32 type?

2, in the code [example](https://github.com/NVIDIA-developer-blog/code-samples/blob/master/posts/tensor-cores/simpleTensorCoreGEMM.cu#L124), why the scale factor `alpha` and `beta` is needed? in the example, they are set to `2.0f`

code snippet from NV blog:

```
for(int i=0; i < c_frag.num_elements; i++) {
         c_frag.x[i] = alpha * acc_frag.x[i] + beta * c_frag.x[i];
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The Tensorcore designers in this case chose to provide a FP32 accumulate option so that the results of many multiply-accumulate steps could be represented both with greater precision (more mantissa bits) as well as greater range (more exponent bits).    This was considered valuable for the overall computational problems they wanted to support, including HPC and AI calculations.  The product of two FP16 numbers might be not representable in FP16, whereas many more or most products of two FP16 numbers will be representable in FP32.
2. The scale factors `alpha` and `beta` are provided so that the provided GEMM operation could easily correspond to the well-known [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) [GEMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms#Level_3) operation, which is widely used in numerical computation.  This allows developers to more easily use the Tensorcore capability to provide a commonly used calculation paradigm in existing numerical computation codes.  It is the same reason that the CUBLAS GEMM implementation provides these adjustable parameters.

Comment: Hi Robert, I have one question on this [line](https://github.com/NVIDIA-developer-blog/code-samples/blob/master/posts/tensor-cores/simpleTensorCoreGEMM.cu#L110) ```wmma::mma_sync(acc_frag, a_frag, b_frag, acc_frag);```, why does it take 4 parameters? I think ```acc_frag = a_frag*b_frag```, in what cases we need another ```acc_frag```? Sorry I didnt find any related documents.

Comment: Remember what you said the function implements?  In your question you stated this: "when using tensor core for `D=A*B+C`", D,A,B,C makes 4 parameters.  The reason that two are the same in this particular example is we are asking it to compute `C=A*B+C`, which is fine.  See [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#wmma-description).  That is part of the programming guide, and it is probably the most important document for learners.  You could quickly find this just by searching that doc for `mma_sync`.  Might be useful for future research.